# Assets not available via API

Tags: planet

I am attempting to download a bunch of 4 band basic scene data, the search returns results, however, the asset link is just an empty dictionary.

When I search for the image ID on scenes explorer, the image is available.

```
    scenes = results.json()['features']
    if len(scenes)!= 0:
        image = sess.get(scenes[0]['_links']['assets'])
```

there is an asset link:
https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/PSScene4Band/items/20171212_054612_1022/assets/'

However, there is not image at this link nor a link to activate the image

Comment: this link requires user and password!Add a screenshot o something like that

Answer (score 1):

This likely means that you don't have permission to download the image. If you signed up for a free Planet API key, you get access to the full archive of California imagery (with a two-week delay) under a CC BY-SA 4.0 license. You can search for images outside California, but you won't have download permission. We're working on better error messages for users so that you don't just get an empty dictionary with no context.

Comment: Still getting an empty dictionary with no context 1.5 years later.