# Search API for PSScene4Band/PSScene3Band/PSOrthoTile not return item ID

Tags: planet

I'm trying to search and then download clips of some shots across California, but am running into an issue. It's potentially the same issue as [Assets not available via API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265212/assets-not-available-via-api), but that question doesn't have enough detail for me to know.

Using the API, I cannot get an image IDs for images in california that I can otherwise download with /explorer, for example item 20171218_181808_102f. I can get image IDs when I query the REOrthoTile item type, but the search API returns empty feature arrays for PSOrthoTile, PSScene4Band, or PSScene3Band queries, both analytic and visual. I think my permissions should let me access the other item types since it's in california. I checked my filters to make sure it matches my /explorer query, and I think it's the same.

Can you help me figure out what's going on?

My search request for PSScene4Band returns something like this:

```
{'_links': {'_first': 'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/searches/b0acb989064a4c5fa5da0b13c86c07a3/results?_page=eyJxdWVyeV9wYXJhbXMiOiB7fSwgInNvcnRfcHJldiI6IGZhbHNlLCAicGFnZV9zaXplIjogMjUwLCAic29ydF9ieSI6ICJwdWJsaXNoZWQiLCAic29ydF9zdGFydCI6IG51bGwsICJzb3J0X2xhc3RfaWQiOiBudWxsLCAic29ydF9kZXNjIjogdHJ1ZX0%3D', '_next': None, '_self': 'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/searches/b0acb989064a4c5fa5da0b13c86c07a3/results?_page=eyJxdWVyeV9wYXJhbXMiOiB7fSwgInNvcnRfcHJldiI6IGZhbHNlLCAicGFnZV9zaXplIjogMjUwLCAic29ydF9ieSI6ICJwdWJsaXNoZWQiLCAic29ydF9zdGFydCI6IG51bGwsICJzb3J0X2xhc3RfaWQiOiBudWxsLCAic29ydF9kZXNjIjogdHJ1ZX0%3D'}, 'features': [], 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
```

Searching for REOrthoTile gets me a big features array filled with stuff, including the id key that I'm looking for.

Here's the search code:

https://github.com/earthmancash2/planet-satellite-fetching/blob/master/planet_image_fetching.py#L95-L148

https://github.com/earthmancash2/planet-satellite-fetching/blob/master/PlanetAPIParams.py

Any ideas for what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not trace completely through your code, but I see an implication that usable_data is part of your query.  I do not believe that the usable_data field is being set to a non-zero value currently for at least some PlanetScope products (see https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/PSScene3Band/items/20171218_181808_102f for instance).  I would suggest dropping the usable_data clause from your query.

In the future it might be helpful to include the final query url you issue in your question.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you for finding that extra filter in my query code. I will make sure to print the full API call in the future for questions like this.